# Is it possible to boot already installed version of Ubuntu from within Win7, e.g. with a vm?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, virtual-machine

I have both Ubuntu 12.10 and Win7 installed. I use the former mostly for scientific simulations and the latter for applications.

The problem I came across with this configuration is that the simulations take quite a while, and I'm not satisfied enough with solutions like Wine to run the Windows apps while the simulation runs.

I would rather not install the simulation programs again, since it took quite an effort.  So, is it possible to boot the already installed version of Ubuntu from within Windows 7 via VirtualBox or or something else?

Answer (score 1):

VMware workstation allows you boot a VM from a physical disk/partition. I am not sure if virtualbox will do the same.

You have to be careful to make sure that the host OS doesn't have the disk/partition  mounted otherwise you could end up with both the host and guest writing to the file system at the same time which will corrupt the data.

In Linux I would make sure it is not mounted and in Windows I would go to the drive settings and remove the drive letter.

Here is a guide on doing this using VMware - http://www.vmware.com/pdf/dualboot_tech_note.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boot image from your current system(Ubuntu 12.04) and then put it on a partition.

Use remastersys.

http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html

Please read the instruction carefully.

1. In Firefox, go to :

   http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key.

   save file as text someplace where you can find it.

   2. In synaptic, go to Settings/Repositories; select `Authentication` tab and `Import Key File` just downloaded.
   3. Still in synaptic, go to `Other Software tab` and click `Add`, then enter the apt line: 
                                                                                       `deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu oneiric main`

   **4. After adding it, a new apt line will automatically added ended with `Source`. You need to uncheck it**

   5. Leave the repositories tab and "Reload".
   6. Search for remastersys and select for install. Edit/Apply Marked Changes.

Source: Askubuntu

Answer (score 0):

On my current computer I have both Linux and Windows 7 installed on one HDD and I'm able to boot to Linux from Windows using VMware Player 5.

Create a VM with parameters you require and add a new `Hard Disk` using `Use physical disk (for advanced users)` and check `Use individual partitions` - select partitions your Ubuntu installation uses. Depending on your Linux installation's configuration you might have to fiddle around with GRUB, but it should work out of the box.